# How to find a line with the longest word?

Tags: python-3.x, list

I need to find the line, that contains the longest word from a txt file. I can find the longest word but I am not able to find in which line that word is.
Here is the part of the code that works for me. I've tried a bunch of ways to find the line but I failed (I am a begginer at python).

```
def reading():
    doc = open("C:/Users/s.txt", "r", encoding= 'utf-8') 
    docu = doc
    return docu
def longest_word_place(document):
    words = document.read().split()
    i = 0
    max = 0
    max_place = 0
    for i in range(len(words)):
        if len(words[i]) > max:                                 
            max = len(words[i])
            max_place = i
    return max_place
document = reading()
print(longest_word_place(document))
```

Comment: First of all, you need to split the text into its lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar to other approaches, but uses `enumerate` as a line counter and checks each word (versus each line):

```
with open("phrases.txt", "r") as file:
    lines = file.readlines()
    
max_word = ""
max_word_line = 0

for line_index, each_line in enumerate(lines, 1):
    words_in_line = each_line.strip().split()
    for each_word in words_in_line:
        if len(each_word) > len(max_word):
            max_word = each_word
            max_word_line = line_index
            
print(f"{max_word = }, {max_word_line = }")
```

Output:

```
max_word = 'bandwidth-monitored', max_word_line = 55
```

Answer (score 0):

You can keep a counter that keeps track of the line number you're on as you iterate through the lines in the file. Something like:

```py
with open('data.txt', 'r') as file:
    lines = file.readlines()

counter = 0
max_length = 0
max_length_line = 0
for line in lines:
    counter += 1

    word_length = len(line)
    if word_length > max_length:
        max_length = word_length
        max_length_line = counter

print(max_length, max_length_line)
```